# Sorts of relativistic effect around black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, differential-geometry, astrophysics

There are many effects around black holes. In particular it is possible to study the motion of geodesics, calculate tidal tensors, lense-thirring effetcs and so on.

So, beyond tidal effects, geodesic motion, lense-thirring effects, time dilation, **could you please give me examples of general relativistic effects that are heavily based on geometrical quantities?**

Comment: Gravitational lensing effect

Comment: [Good list, bad list](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list) For me, this falls into the bad-list category.

Comment: GR is a geometry-based theory. *All* of its predictions are “heavily based on geometrical quantities”.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a bit difficult to classify general relativistic effects to be "beyond" time dilation or those you mentioned, so I will list a few that come to my mind right now even if they might be "basic".

- **Shapiro delay**: The travel time of light close to massive objects is slightly longer than if the massive objects was not there.
- **Gravitational waves**: Systems that have a non-vanishing quadrupole moment will radiate gravitational waves. The currently most studied systems (because they are the strongest emitters) are binary systems consisting of black holes and/or neutron stars. Even isolated, deformed stars or objects will radiate, however, at a much less power.
- **Existence of singularities**: There are solutions to Einstein's equations that feature singularities,  e.g. the singularity at the center of a black hole where geodesics end, or the Big Bang where geodesics begin.
- **Event horizons**: The geometry of spacetime is fundamentally different inside and outside an event horizon. Linked to these are Hawking radiation or the Penrose process.

This list is not comprehensive as there are certainly effects like light bending (not beyond Lense-Thirring) missing or those that I can't think of right now.